# "No instance of overloaded function 'getline'.."

Tags: c++, getline

part of the code:

```
string name;

    cin >> name;

    ifstream userFile( name + ".txt");
    if (userFile.good()){
      // read away
        cout << "Password? \n";

        string pw;

        cin >> pw;

        //checking if pw matches
        getline(userFile, 1);
```

So i am using namespace std and include sstream string fstream iostream.
It says the argumented types are (std::ifstream, int) so what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I thought the 2nd parameter referred to which line you'd like to read. Could anyone explain to me how I select the line I can read in a different way?

Comment: have you included `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>`?

Comment: What's that `1` supposed to do?

Comment: `getline` has the signature `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);`. There is no overload taking an `int` as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: umm...where do you want to store the line after you read it?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: What are you trying to do with `getline(userFile, 1)`? What is 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [std::istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), it does not have a prototype that takes a `ifstream` object and a   `size_t`.

> ```
> istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
> istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
> ```

Also quoting from [std::getline (string)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/),it has  the following:

> istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
>      istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str, char delim);
>      istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
>      istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);

You are using `getline` in the wrong way.
If you are trying to use `getline` to read lines from file, you can try the following:

```
string currLine;
getline(userFile, currLine);
//do something with current line
```

Comment: As I am pretty new to C++/file-coding, how do I fix this? I assume I've to use something like getline(myFile, ??) ?

Comment: @user2376038 I edited the post as response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do have a question though. Does this read the entire file now, or does it only read the first line? Because I might want to store more information in this file then just the user's password.

Comment: @user2376038 Yes, it will read one line, you need a while loop to read file line by line in this way. Check out this thread for better explanation:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841931/c-did-getline-read-entire-line

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline` has the following signature:

> **`std::getline`**
>
> ```
>    template< class T, class U, class Allocator >
>    std::basic_istream<T, U>& getline(std::basic_istream<T, U>& input,
>                                        std::basic_string<T,U, Allocator>& str,
>                                        CharT delim);
> ```

That is, it takes an instance of `std::istream` and `std::string`. This method is used to consume the entire line of a stream `input` into a buffer `str`.

This doesn't seem to be the method you are looking for. You said you needed to check if `userFile` matches the password. If then you should try this:

```
std::string password;

userFile >> password // insert entire line into password

if (password == "1") // check if password is equal to 1
{
    ...
}
```